# Copy annotation in a Personal GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arccatalog

I  tend to work with personal GDB and with complex labels, when done I convert them to annotations, creating the annotation feature class and the "Anno" relationship, both into the personal GDB.

How can I do if I want to create a copy of that set of annotations to change a few of them?

In the end I need to keep both, the original one and the amended one.

If I try to copy the annotation directly in ArcCatalog not only the Annotation feature class is copied, the "Anno" relationship and the original shapefile (where the labels originally come from) is copied as "Shapefile_1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this with feature-linked annotation.

If you still have the map that created the complex labels (i.e. the annotation), you could create a new feature-linked annotation from that. If it has similar data and labeling rules, it will produce similar results, assuming you did not move/edit the annotation too much. It should have its own annotation relationship pointing to the source file. That is how I create feature-linked annotation at different scales.

It helps to keep the earlier annotation feature turned on but somewhat transparent and below your new feature so you can easily see where you may need to move annotation in your new feature class. Annotation is also a polygon feature, so you can do spatial selects to compare the two annotation features.